# "Last Week" Date Conditional Styles in Jasper Reports

Tags: styles, jasper-reports, conditional-statements, date, report

I am trying to create a style that makes dates from the last week in bold. I have only been able to get it to work by putting in an explicit date like below. I would like to have a dynamic "last week" based on the current date.

```
<style name="Date_Bold" isBold="false">    
    <conditionalStyle>
       <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{$F{account_date}.toString() > '2011-10-17 00:00:00']]></conditionExpression>
       <style isBold="true"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this expression to get 'last week' (today minus seven days)

```xml
<![CDATA[new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (7 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))]]>
```

You can see also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902653/java-util-date-seven-days-ago) for better understanding this solution.

You can try to get date via `SQL query` and put the result value to the new `Date` field.
   It would be something like this for Oracle:

```sql
 SELECT account_date, sysdate-7 as last_week, ... FROM table ...
```

It would be something like this for MS SQL:

```sql
SELECT account_date, (GETDATE() - 1) as last_week , ... FROM table ...
```

Another way to pass date from code via `parameter`.

Or you can try to import [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library for example. [Here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/scriptlet/index.html#scriptlet) is the sample of scriplet using.

Comment: Used the SQL method. That was way easier.