# Firestore - Creating a query where results are within last 7 days

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query data with in the last 7 days using Firebase Firestore, I have a stored the date as a field in the document but i dont know how to create a query where it only adds data from the last 7 days.

```java
db.collection("dataToSave").whereEqualTo("Email", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail())
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < QuerySnapshot > () {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < QuerySnapshot > task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()) {

                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.get("Date").toString() + document.get("Status"));
                    thisWeeksClockings.add(document.get("Date").toString() + (" ") + document.get("Status"));

                    //                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),document.getData().toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
            }

            adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(thisWeeksClockings);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you try `whereGreatThan("datefield", dateObjectOfSevenDaysAgo)`? Or is your problem how to [create a `Date` object for 7 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902653/java-util-date-seven-days-ago)?

Comment: The problem is more so how to create a date object for 7 days ago , apologies

Comment: No worries . The question I linked shows how to do that.